# Insert info not working in sqlite in android studio for practice

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image]

Hey guys I've been trying to insert some data into a table ive created in android studio heres the code.

```
package database.oxbir.com.databae;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Oxbir on 28/10/2018.
 */

public class DataModelLayer extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "oxbir";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_NAME = "users";

    public static final String COL_ID =  "id";
    public static final String COL_NAME =  "name";
    public static final String COL_FAMILY =  "family";
    public static final String COL_AGE =  "age";

    public static final String Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_NAME + "(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_NAME + "TEXT," +
            COL_FAMILY + "TEXT," +
            COL_AGE + "INTEGER);";

    Context context;

    public DataModelLayer(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(Query);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long addInfo (String name, String family, int age){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_FAMILY, family);
        contentValues.put(COL_AGE, age);

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TBL_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
package database.oxbir.com.databae;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Oxbir on 28/10/2018.
 */

public class DataModelLayer extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "oxbir";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_NAME = "users";

    public static final String COL_ID =  "id";
    public static final String COL_NAME =  "name";
    public static final String COL_FAMILY =  "family";
    public static final String COL_AGE =  "age";

    public static final String Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_NAME + "(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL_NAME + "TEXT," +
            COL_FAMILY + "TEXT," +
            COL_AGE + "INTEGER);";

    Context context;

    public DataModelLayer(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(Query);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long addInfo (String name, String family, int age){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_FAMILY, family);
        contentValues.put(COL_AGE, age);

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TBL_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

When ever i call this activity i get `id=1` message.

I found that the activity was being executed with no problems what so ever the app didn't crash so I decided to toast the insert query to see if anything was wrong with it.

as far as i can tell it looks okay buy as soon as I included.

In my code the app crashes( temp contains the query i just toasted )

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pasted the exact code then you have error in the create sql of the table, so change to this:

```
public static final String Query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_NAME + "(" +
        COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
        COL_FAMILY + " TEXT," +
        COL_AGE + " INTEGER);";
```

I included spaces between the name of the fields and the type.  
Now uninstall the app first and the run again. 
 
 
Also make the `addInfo()` method simpler:

```
public long addInfo (String name, String family, int age){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_FAMILY, family);
    contentValues.put(COL_AGE, age);

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TBL_NAME, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close()
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: where is table users and where is oxbir database

Comment: Yes the code working. but users table, where is SQLite Expert added?

Comment: SQLite Expert has nothing to do with the database in your device/emulator. Your app creates the database and the table inside the device/emulator when you run it 1st time.